# Why is the order of bit fields in the bytes of structs not defined by the language itself?

Tags: c++, struct, endianness, bit-fields

I came across a problem today where I discovered the way the bit fields in my bytes are ordered is dependent on the endianness of my processor. Take the next example:

```
struct S {
    uint8_t a : 3;
    uint8_t b : 5;
};
```

This struct takes one byte but the bit layout depends on the machine:

- Little endian: b4 b3 b2 b1 b0 a2 a1 a0
- Big endian: a2 a1 a0 b4 b3 b2 b1

So on a little endian machine it starts filling from the LSB and on a big endian machine it start filling from the MSB. I once heard Stroustrup say it's a main goal to achieve portability across platforms but leaving some things like this is not portable at all. If I were to send this struct over a connection to someone, how would he know which bits mapped to which fields in the struct? Would it not have been easier if the order was fixed? What's the reasoning behind the choice of leaving this open to the processor and compiler? The only safe option is to use bit shifts and masks which uses a lot more code. It would have been so much easier if me and my co-workers could have counted on a fixed order, the little endian way for example, but there certainly must have been a reason why chose not to do it.

Comment: Probably has nothing to do with the endianness of the processor and everything to do with an arbitrary decision by the compiler writers. Which compilers did you observe this with?

Comment: Probably for compatibility with C, which also doesn't define the order.

Comment: Questions about the reason for language design choices are not really appropriate here, answers will just be opinion and speculation.

Comment: @MarkRansom His question is about why the language leaves the decision to compiler writers in the first place.

Comment: @MarkRansom I use g++

Comment: C++ doesn't dictate memory layouts in regards to padding either, so your over-the-wire argument doesn't hold.

Comment: @Barmar Where can I go to for questions like this then? And true, I was wondering why it was up to the compiler writers to make the decision. It's not really nice if different compilers have different solutions for something.

Comment: @Barmar sometimes compiler decisions are documented. I've seen this more with Python which has a single point of definition, but I wouldn't rule it out for C++ which has discussion forums. As for my previous comment, that was meant to clear up a possible misconception.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x You're right, but if you use #pragma(pack,1) there is no padding and you'll always have the problem I posed.

Comment: @Confituur Can't think of a good place to ask a question like this.

Comment: @Confituur g++ on both platforms? Interesting. Similar versions?

Comment: No matter where you ask, you'll just get speculation. Gotta ask Stroustrup.

Comment: @Confituur that's up to the implementation, just as much as the bitfields

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, the order of the bits is different for big and little endian machines with the same compiler.

Comment: This question can be simplified. The bits in `uint16_t` and even `char` are also not specified. Given that, asking about bitfields becomes sort of moot.

Comment: The rules in C are like that; C++ inherited the rules from C.  And the rules in C are like that because the state of the world (of compilers) when it was standardized was as chaotic as the rules suggest.  The C89/C90 standard committee tried to avoid specifying the standard in a way that meant that working compilers could not be compatible with it without breaking the code that their users had written for it.

Comment: It's not only about endianness. gcc and VC++ will have a different layout on the same hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not defined by the language so that it can accommodate the exact situation you've discovered. For bit fields in a byte it makes no difference, but bit fields can occupy larger integer types. Consider this example:

```
struct bf
{
    uint16_t a : 5;
    uint16_t b : 11;
};
```

In order for the bits of a field to be adjacent in memory, the bits in a byte *must* be laid out differently depending on the endianness of the processor.

Big endian:

```
aaaaabbb bbbbbbbb
```

Little endian:

```
bbbbbbbb bbbaaaaa
```